# Detecting and reading embedded filesystems on desktop Linux

Tags: file-format, embedded, memory-dump, flash, router

I have some data from a NAND chip, dumped using the built in *nanddump* utility on the embedded device.

This is the device information: https://openwrt.org/toh/bt/homehub_v5a The NAND chip is 128MiB Spansion ML01G100BHI00

I have processed the dump using the Python ubi_reader (https://github.com/jrspruitt/ubi_reader) which shows information that fits and produces some files:

```
128K    img-2097163413_vol-caldata.ubifs
15M img-2097163413_vol-FFS.ubifs
21M img-2097163413_vol-OpenRG.ubifs
```

I've tried mounting any of these (especially the last two) with commands including the below:

```
sudo mount -o loop img-2097163413_vol-FFS.ubifs /mnt/tmp
sudo mount -t jffs2 -o loop img-2097163413_vol-FFS.ubifs /mnt/tmp
sudo mount -t ubifs -o loop img-2097163413_vol-FFS.ubifs /mnt/tmp
```

But I get different errors, including:

```
mount: /mnt/tmp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop16, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and have the *mtd-utils* installed. I don't know if I need a special kernel module (or a custom kernel build) to be able to read these on a desktop build of Linux?

Running binwalk gives quite a lot of output, but I'm not convinced it really helps:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             UBIFS filesystem superblock node, CRC: 0x18587199, flags: 0x0, min I/O unit size: 2048, erase block size: 129024, erase block count: 662, max erase blocks: 662, format version: 4, compression type: lzo
129024        0x1F800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x2AB14864, highest inode: 64, commit number: 0
131072        0x20000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xB8679430, highest inode: 64, commit number: 0
133120        0x20800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xCFA58C39, highest inode: 68, commit number: 1
135168        0x21000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x49224F4A, highest inode: 68, commit number: 1
137216        0x21800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xF356AD50, highest inode: 68, commit number: 1
139264        0x22000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x1C09B66E, highest inode: 68, commit number: 2
141312        0x22800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x85E22D40, highest inode: 68, commit number: 3
143360        0x23000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xD2CCE2D1, highest inode: 100, commit number: 4
145408        0x23800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x4FA2D61B, highest inode: 134, commit number: 5
147456        0x24000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x13B828D, highest inode: 178, commit number: 6
149504        0x24800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x462195E8, highest inode: 219, commit number: 7
151552        0x25000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xA8F61781, highest inode: 219, commit number: 8
153600        0x25800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x3A0CCA43, highest inode: 244, commit number: 9
155648        0x26000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xF3B91383, highest inode: 244, commit number: 10
157696        0x26800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xC962E252, highest inode: 267, commit number: 11
159744        0x27000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xB37C99F7, highest inode: 307, commit number: 12
161792        0x27800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x379C342E, highest inode: 347, commit number: 13
163840        0x28000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x906A63C7, highest inode: 347, commit number: 13
165888        0x28800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x2BCBF93, highest inode: 347, commit number: 13
167936        0x29000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x70D2F699, highest inode: 347, commit number: 14
169984        0x29800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x348E6DCE, highest inode: 347, commit number: 15
258048        0x3F000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x2681BD79, highest inode: 64, commit number: 0
260096        0x3F800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x9CF55F63, highest inode: 64, commit number: 0
262144        0x40000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xDBF4931E, highest inode: 68, commit number: 1
264192        0x40800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x6DB08419, highest inode: 68, commit number: 1
266240        0x41000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xFF66584D, highest inode: 68, commit number: 1
268288        0x41800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x10394373, highest inode: 68, commit number: 2
270336        0x42000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x89D2D85D, highest inode: 68, commit number: 3
272384        0x42800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xF65E2982, highest inode: 100, commit number: 4
274432        0x43000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x43922306, highest inode: 134, commit number: 5
276480        0x43800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x156A9DAA, highest inode: 178, commit number: 6
278528        0x44000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x62B35EBB, highest inode: 219, commit number: 7
280576        0x44800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x67935A0C, highest inode: 219, commit number: 8
282624        0x45000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x1E9E0110, highest inode: 244, commit number: 9
284672        0x45800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x9213CFCB, highest inode: 244, commit number: 10
286720        0x46000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xC552174F, highest inode: 267, commit number: 11
288768        0x46800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0xBF4C6CEA, highest inode: 307, commit number: 12
290816        0x47000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x3BACC133, highest inode: 347, commit number: 13
292864        0x47800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x9C5A96DA, highest inode: 347, commit number: 13
294912        0x48000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x47A9DC28, highest inode: 347, commit number: 13
296960        0x48800         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x6483E9BE, highest inode: 347, commit number: 14
299008        0x49000         UBIFS filesystem master node, CRC: 0x38BE98D3, highest inode: 347, commit number: 15
9045944       0x8A07B8        MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 10
```

Is it possible to mount these images? Otherwise, what is the best way to access the information on the NAND dump?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `binwalk -e yourdump.bin`. It will then try to extract the files within your dump and if a filesystem is found it will also extract those.